# How to get data from sql server with condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with Sql Server!

My question is: I have 15000 records in my customer table , And I want to process first 5000 records in one day, next day I process on next 5000 records on daily basis. Every day operation is perform in limited number of records, Data of customer table changes frequently. And also get number of pending records which are not processed. Please give your helpful suggestions how to do this . Thanks

**Further Details:**

1. datetime stamp using in table
2. Fields:  [first_name] ,[middle_name] ,[last_name] ,[created] ,[created_by] ,[customer_number]

Comment: Can you post the schema of the table? Can you suggest if you keep a datetime stamp if the row has been processed?  if you do its as simple as Select top 5000 * from DataTable where datetimeprocessed is null order by IdentityCol ASC

Comment: how customer table changes affects your daily processing ?

Comment: ,[first_name]
      ,[middle_name]
      ,[last_name]
      ,[created]
      ,[created_by]
   
      ,[customer_number]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way can be by adding two column (if not exist). `updated_at` and `processed_at`. `updated_at` column will be updated on update of row. `processed_at` column will be updated when you started process that row by your daily job. Now your query will be something like.

```
select * from your_table where updated_at > processed_at limit 5000;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you have some form of ID in your table...

So you set a start date in your procedure, and compare to that (I have used '2016-01-01'):

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, row_number() over(order by customer_id) as r_ord
from Mytable t1
)
select CTE.*
from CTE
where (mod(datediff(day, '2016-01-01', getdate()),3) = 0 and r_ord <= 5000)
or  (mod(datediff(day, '2016-01-01', getdate()),3) = 1 and r_ord between 5001 and 10000)
or  (mod(datediff(day, '2016-01-01', getdate()),3) = 2 and r_ord > 10000)
```